# What is a zero argument constructor in Dart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

What is a zero-argument constructor in Dart flutter?

while creating a bloc in flutter I am receiving the following error

```
  The superclass 'Bloc<QuoteEvent, QuoteState>' doesn't have a zero argument constructor.
Try declaring a zero argument constructor in 'Bloc<QuoteEvent, QuoteState>', or explicitly invoking a different constructor in 'Bloc<QuoteEvent, QuoteState>'.
```

kindly guide how to fix it. thanks

below is code

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

import 'package:random_quote/repositories/repositories.dart';
import 'package:random_quote/models/models.dart';
import 'package:random_quote/bloc/bloc.dart';

class QuoteBloc extends Bloc<QuoteEvent, QuoteState> {
  final QuoteRepository repository;

  QuoteBloc({@required this.repository}) : assert(repository != null);

  @override
  QuoteState get initialState => QuoteEmpty();

  @override
  Stream<QuoteState> mapEventToState(QuoteEvent event) async* {
    if (event is FetchQuote) {
      yield QuoteLoading();
      try {
        final Quote quote = await repository.fetchQuote();
        yield QuoteLoaded(quote: quote);
      } catch (_) {
        yield QuoteError();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code sample of your bloc class.
Do you use flutter_bloc package?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/10595176/mol0ko 
thanks, I have added the bloc code
yes I am using flutter_bloc package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A zero-argument constructor is literally a constructor that can be invoked with zero arguments.  This includes constructors that take only optional arguments.

If you have a derived class that does not *explicitly* invoke its base class constructor, the derived class's constructors will *implicitly* invoke the default (unnamed) constructor in the base class with zero arguments.  If you need to call a named constructor in the base class or if you need to pass arguments, you will need to invoke the base class constructor explicitly.

In your case, `QuoteBloc` derives from `Bloc<QuoteEvent, QuoteState>`, but the `QuoteBloc` constructor does not explicitly invoke any constructor from `Bloc`, which apparently does not provide a default, zero-argument constructor.

Answer (score 6):

`initialState` property was removed from [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) since v5.0.0. Here is [migration guide](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=%E2%9D%97initialstate-has-been-removed).

You should use super() constructor instead:

```
class QuoteBloc extends Bloc<QuoteEvent, QuoteState> {
  final QuoteRepository repository;

  QuoteBloc({@required this.repository}) : 
    assert(this.repository != null),
    super(QuoteEmpty());

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SomeClass();//this is zero argument constructor
SomeClass2(String argument1);//this is one argument constructor
SomeClass3(String argument1,String argument2);//this is 2 argument constructor
```